How to strikethrough a text if the text is the same in another cell using conditional formatting?
I am making a table assignment for the guests for my brother's wedding. I want to know if it's possible to conditionally format to strikethrough a cell that has the same text as another cell. In this case if I already assigned a name to a certain table (a specific cell), I want it to automatically have a strikethrough.



GUEST NAMES
TABLE ASSIGNMENTS
TABLE ASSIGNMENTS




John
TABLE 1
TABLE 2


Stacey
Jacob
Stacey


Jacob
Hannah
John


Hannah






Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

Your conditional formating rule would be:
Range:          C3:Z22
Custom Formula:  =COUNTIF(TOCOL($B$3:B$22,1),C3)

This assumes you have a maximum of 20 guests per table. You can change the max by adjusting 22 in both the range and the formula.
I added a sample Sheet with a more advanced approach that you can play with if interested.  Anyone with the link can edit it so you should probably make a copy to your own Drive while it is working

The guest list is managed on one tab
The seating arrangements on the other.

